# Efficient method to update one field with different values in a django model

Tags: django, django-models

I have many pk-value in a dictionary and I want to update the object with his new value.

```
to_update = [{'id':id1,'value':value1}, ... ]
```

Now i'm doing this:

```
for t in to_update:
    Mymodel.objects.filter(pk=t['id']).update(myfield=t['value'])
```

I think that i can do this in a better way, but i didn't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the most efficient way. `QuerySet.update()` is converted directly to an `UPDATE` statement, and there is no more efficient way of doing it than that.

Comment: but how do i do a multiple update with diferent values and different ids?

Comment: You can't. Just like you can't do it in SQL.

Comment: Manual management of database transactions (`@commit_manually` and so on) could result in speed boost in some environments.

Comment: Sure there's a way to do it in SQL - a CASE block with a WHEN clause.  Like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4374285/update-multiple-rows-with-different-values-in-sql