# Update multiple rows with different values in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-update

I have a table like this:

```
SKU            Size
A              10
B              10
C              10
D              10
E              10
F              10
G              10
```

I want to change it to:

```
SKU            Size
A              20
B              10
C              30
D              10
E              80
F              10
G              60
```

I have more than 3000 rows of records to update. How can I do that with SQL update command ?

Comment: And what would be the criteria for updating various rows to different values?

Comment: How can we tell what transform to apply to each row?

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific about the structure of your database. Are each of those columns or are some values of columns?

Comment: Is the SKU the primarykey on your table? Why are the values changing?

Comment: Maybe he want "update table set Size= sizeof (SKU);"  ^^

Comment: Why do people not disclose a name for their table? This is not only you, Bob - it is a very common problem with SQL questions on SO.  It is exasperating because people answering the question have to come up with a table name in the proposed SQL.

Comment: [duplicate to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4374285/update-multiple-rows-with-different-values-in-sql)

Answer (score 23):

```
UPDATE T
SET Size = CASE SKU
    WHEN 'A' THEN 20
    WHEN 'B' THEN 10
    WHEN 'C' THEN 30
    WHEN ...
END
```

Or there may be a formula for calculating the size, but you've failed to give it in your question (Or we may have to switch to a more complex CASE expression, but again, too little detail in the question).

Comment: No formula for calculating the size. I'll give it a try with your suggestion. Just need to copy the info from the excel & add them into the SQL command. It will start something like this:- UPDATE T
SET Size = CASE SKU
    WHEN 'A' THEN 20
    WHEN 'B' THEN 10
    WHEN 'C' THEN 30
    WHEN ... (all the way to 3,000 records)
END

Comment: Worked great for me, thank you Damien. I was changing the literals in a description column based on a degree name (all text fields). Saved a bunch of unnecessary UPDATE statements.

Comment: I was using the above query with primary key as the `WHEN` condition. For a large table (~4M records), my query worked much faster if I added a `WHERE id in (...)` clause.

Answer (score 5):

Create a table with the mapping of SKU to new size; update the master table from that.

Many dialects of SQL have a notation for doing updates via joined tables.  Some do not.  This will work where there is no such notation:

```
CREATE TABLE SKU_Size_Map
(
     SKU     CHAR(16) NOT NULL,
     Size    INTEGER NOT NULL
);
...Populate this table with the SKU values to be set...
...You must have such a list...

UPDATE MasterTable
   SET Size = (SELECT Size FROM SKU_Size_Map
                WHERE MasterTable.SKU = SKU_Size_Map.Size)
 WHERE SKU IN (SELECT SKU FROM SKU_Size_Map);
```

The main WHERE condition is need to avoid setting the size to null where there is no matching row.

You can probably also do it with a MERGE statement.  But the key insight for any of these notations is that you need a table to do the mapping between SKU and size.  You either need a table or you need an algorithm, and the sample data doesn't suggest an algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of **OpenXML** to resolve your issue

example

```
declare @i int

exec sp_xml_preparedocument @i output, 
'<mydata>
  <test xmlID="3" xmlData="blah blah blah"/>
  <test xmlID="1" xmlData="blah"/>
</mydata>'

insert into test 
select xmlID, xmlData 
from OpenXml(@i, 'mydata/test')
with (xmlID int, xmlData nvarchar(30))
where xmlID not in (select xmlID from test)

update test
set test.xmlData = ox.xmlData
from OpenXml(@i, 'mydata/test')
with (xmlID int, xmlData nvarchar(30)) ox
where test.xmlID = ox.xmlID

exec sp_xml_removedocument @i
```

Comment: It is a viable approach in SQL Server (or another supporting RDBMS) and sometimes (don't laugh) the "best" way to get or pass the data is in XML. Not that I really recommend it here, but +1 anyway ;-)

Answer (score -1):

Just do...

```
UPDATE [yourTable] SET Size = 20 WHERE SKU = 'A'
```

And do this for all values you want to change...

Comment: I dont think that's possible. I hv more than 3000 SKUs & most of them hv different sizes. 10 was set as a default value & now, I hv to update it with the correct value though some SKUs will remain as 10.

Comment: Do you have a list of some sort that tells you what to set? Like excel? you might generate the SQL Statement out of this...

Comment: @Bob And what difference does it make? :-) The input comes from somewhere so it's just a matter of turning that into one (or many) appropriate SQL statements. If the value is to remain the same, don't set it or, if setting it keeps the same value, then so be it.

Comment: @Bob: it must be documentet somewhere. So can't you just generate the sql statement with my sql as template?

Comment: The whole idea behind this question was to do this in a single query I think. Consider giving a try to @Damien_The_Unbeliever's answer

Answer (score -1):

Well, if you don't have a formula to calculate your `Size`s, and you don't have a file or an Excel sheet with the data that you can massage into your table, you'll just have to get some luckless intern to type something like

```
 UPDATE <table> SET Size = <value> WHERE SKU = '<key>'
```

3000 times.

If you are that intern, I'd suggest giving us a little more information...

Comment: Is it now? You refer, I take it, to the "massage file data" part, right? Because I'm at a loss how Perl would help with vague verbal instructions or numbers on a piece of paper, or whatever it is that the intern might have to deal with.

Answer (score -4):

Since you wanted to change the whole column, drop that particular column by using this:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
DROP COLUMN column_name;
```

then create a new column using:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
ADD column_name varchar(80);
```